# Upgrading CentOS 7 to OpenSSL 1.1.1 by yum install openssl11

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, centos7

I use Centos 7 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k (openssl-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64.rpm)

I've tried to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.1.1c by:

```
yum install openssl11
```

which basically installs: openssl11-1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64.rpm and openssl11-libs-1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

It doesn't upgrade by overrides openssl 1.0.2 with openssl 1.1.1 but install openssl11 and its RPMs along with the existing openssl version.

when I try to uninstall openssl 1.0.2, it causes some dependencies issues, which make perfectly sense since openssl11 provides openssl11 and not openssl:

`openssl is needed by (installed) python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64`

`openssl is needed by (installed) pcs-0.9.162-5.el7.centos.x86_64`

`openssl is needed by (installed) rng-tools-6.3.1-3.el7.x86_64`

`/usr/bin/openssl is needed by (installed) authconfig-6.2.8-30.el7.x86_64`

What should I do to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can't uninstall openssl 1.0.2 CentOS requires it and you cannot upgrade it until they decide to do ( but they won't , you'll have to upgrade to CentOS 8)

Openssl11 is for "spot" usage with specific environments if you need it.

Comment: I'm the package maintainer of openssl11 in EPEL 7 and yes, openssl11 is indeed meant for "spot" usage only, _not_ as an upgrade/replacement of the regular openssl package. And [RHBZ#1416715](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1416715) is the reference that RHEL/CentOS 7 won't get a newer OpenSSL version.